# How to hide shadow between two adjoined divs

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I have two divs on top of each other (adjoined) and they booth as one unit shall have one box-shadow. Now the upper div gives shadow on the lower div which I don't want. I have tried to manipulate it with a "z-index:2" to be more on top but no luck.

I would like to hide the bottom shadow of the upper div and hide the top shadow of the lower div

Also I don't want the shadow to fold into the adjoined sides. The two divs should be one unit having one shadow

In my example here I have simpified the html

```
<div class="upper-box" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
</div>
<div class="lower-div" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
</div>
```

In the jsfiddle the css is all in original and here goes all the work of change.

```
.upper-box {
    border-top: 0 none;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0;

    /* Expanded panel gets emphasized by a shadow */
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 50px 7px rgba(255,255,255,0.75),
                0px 6px 50px 7px rgba(88,88,88,0.75),
                0px 6px 50px 7px rgba(88,88,88,0.75),
                0px 6px 50px 7px rgba(88,88,88,0.75)
                ;
    z-index: 3;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-width: 0px;
    position: relative;
 }    

 .lower-div {
    border-bottom: 0px;

    box-shadow: 0px 6px 50px 7px rgba(88,88,88,0.75);
    z-index: 2;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

I would like to hide the bottom shadow of the upper div and hide the top shadow of the lower div

Also I don't want the shadow to fold into the adjoined sides. The two divs should be one unit having one shadow

Here is my live demo

`https://jsfiddle.net/y289sdeb/`

Comment: Sorry for the weird scroll text in the middle of my question. How can I delete it?

Comment: Just edit your question with the edit link below it. Make sure to include your code in your questions itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pseudo element, like this

```css
.upper-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
}
.lower-div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
}
.upper-box::after,
.lower-div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 50px 7px rgba(88, 88, 88, 0.75);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper-box">

</div>

<div class="lower-div">

</div>
```

Based on a comment, a wrapper can be used

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.upper-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.lower-div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 50px 7px rgba(88, 88, 88, 0.75);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <div class="upper-box">

  </div>

  <div class="lower-div">

  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Very close =) 
When I try your solution a "new" space of 2px width has been introduced between the divs.
Also I am not allowed to set the backround to "white" since this is a list where every odd line is gray

Comment: @user2969053 Removed ... though with the existing margin values you wanted that

Comment: @user2969053 Updated my answer, added a 2:nd sample.